# How to get Percentage of Total counts for each item in the Map/Dict column?

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, percentage

I have a PySpark dataframe which looks like this, I have a map datatype column Map<Str,Int>

```
 Date              Item (Map<Str,int>)                           Total Items   

2021-02-01    Item_A -> 3, Item_B -> 10, Item_C -> 2                 15
2021-02-02    Item_A -> 1, Item_B -> 5, Item_C ->  7                 13
2021-02-03    Item_A -> 8, Item_B -> 3, Item_C ->  1                 12
```

I want to create a new column which gives me the individual Item dominance percentage from the total number of items. Item_A / total number of items and so on to all other items.
The resulting column should also be a map.

I want something like this:

```
 Date              Item (Map<Str,int>)                    Total Items     Item count % 
                                                                        (item/total items)*100

2021-02-01    Item_A -> 3, Item_B -> 10, Item_C -> 5           15     Item_A -> 20%, Item_B -> 66%, Item_c -> 33%
2021-02-02    Item_A -> 1, Item_B -> 5, Item_C ->  7           13    Item_A -> 7%, Item_B -> 38%, Item_C -> 53%
2021-02-03    Item_A -> 8, Item_B -> 3, Item_C ->  1           12    Item_A -> 66%, Item_B -> 25%, Item_C -> 8.3%
```

My approach:

```py
df = df.withColumn('Item_count_percentage', F.expr('aggregate(map_values(Item), 0 , (acc, x) -> (acc / int(x)/100)'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Spark 3.0+**

  Making use of [`transform_values`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform_values)

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F

  df = df.withColumn(
      'Item count',
      F.expr("transform_values(Item, (k, v) -> round(v / `Total Items` * 100, 1))")
  )
  ```
- **Spark 2.4+**

  Recreating the map ([`map_from_arrays`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_arrays.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_arrays)) by first extracting keys ([`map_keys`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys)), then values ([`map_values`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_values.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_values)) and applying a higher order function ([`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform)) on values.

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F

  df = df.withColumn(
      'Item count',
      F.map_from_arrays(
          F.map_keys('Item'),
          F.expr("transform(map_values(Item), x -> round(x / `Total Items` * 100, 1))")
      )
  )
  ```